# Codeigniter - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this'

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am starting to learn codeigniter. I get this error while trying to run the project.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE), expecting
>   ';' or '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Codeigniter\application\models\post.php
>   on line 5

**My Model-post.php:**

```
class Post extends CI_Model{
    function get_posts($num=20, $start=0)
        $this->db->select()->from('posts')->where('active',1)->order_by('date_added','desc')->limit($start,$num);
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

**My Controller-posts.php:**

```
<?php
class Posts extends CI_Controller{
    function index(){
        $this->load->model('post');
        $data['posts'] = $this->post->get_posts();
        print_r($data['posts']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Compare this function header: `function get_posts($num=20, $start=0)` with this one: `function index(){`

Comment: I think the error is on this line:
`function get_posts($num=20, $start=0)`. You declare a function without opening the brace. Add the opening brace like this `function get_posts($num=20, $start=0) {`
It's surprising you didn't open the brace, yet you are closing it on the second-to-last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function get_posts($num=20, $start=0)
```

You're missing the brace from this function. It should be;

```
function get_posts($num=20, $start=0) {
```

Comment: @AdrienXL wow this answer get's 5 upV for only a typo, no additional errors or anything else to explain or so. To bad that I don't get 35 upV for spotting 7 errors when I'm answering questions.

Comment: Also i just will post this here, since it seems that not many people read this: Vote for close -> off-topic: `This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a` **simple typographical error** `While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner` **unlikely to help future readers** `This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.`

Comment: @Rizier123 Why are you telling me that ? Even if it is not the most exhaustive answer in SO, it stills the only good answer and Craig has been unfairly downvoted, I just upvoted in compensation. No big deal here...

Comment: @AdrienXL Yes, you shouldn't down vote a answer on a bad question only because of the question, that's right! (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255459/3933332) But, this answer is neither good nor helpful. Even the error message alone would be a better answer here. Why? 1. It's only a single and simple typo in OP's code nothing more 2. This can be googled in under 1 sec and there are tunes of duplicates already on SO for this 3. It has no explanation (Also just to note here: You even see that OP understands how to write the code right since he did it right in another place)

Comment: totally agree with @Rizier123 , and moreover this answer could have been a `short and sweet comment + flagged off topic under Typo errors.` flagged it hour ago,